# Evernote Java SDK NoteStoreClient.findNotes() does not find notes

Tags: java, evernote

I am using the Evernote Java SDK with the sandbox account to create a note and search for it.

```java
Note mynote = new Note();
mynote.setTitle("mytitle");
mynote.setContent(content);
Note createdNote = noteStore.createNote(mynote);

NoteFilter filter = new NoteFilter();
String query = "mytitle";
filter.setWords(query);

NoteList notelist = noteStore.findNotes(filter, 0, 10);
```

The creation of the note works fine but unfortunately `findNotes()` just returns an empty list. The same code worked some months ago but now it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the sandbox search is broken. See Evernote forum post https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/120740-searching-is-not-working-in-sandbox-environment/. Little response back from Evernote at this point...